# Show that if $f$ is analytic on $B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$, and $ \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)(z-z_0)=A$ , then, $\oint_{|z-z_0|=r} f(z) dz=2\pi iA$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Show that if $f$ is analytic on $B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ , and $$ \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)(z-z_0)=A$$
then $$\oint_{|z-z_0|=r} f(z) dz=2\pi iA$$ for any $r$ : $0<r<R$

I am not sure how to start, first of all, it looks like the solution requires Cauchy's Formula, but  since we don't know that $f$ is analytic in $z_0$, doesn't that make the domain not simply connected, and thus doesn't allow the use of the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$g(z)=\begin{cases}(z-z_0)f(z)&\text{ if }z\ne z_0\\A&\text{ if }z=z_0.\end{cases}$$Then $g$ is continuous at $z_0$ and therefore, by [Riemann's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem), it is holomorphic. So, Cauchy's integral formula telles us that$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathrm dz=g(z_0)=A.$$So,$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-z_0|=r}f(z)\,\mathrm dz=A.$$

Comment: Would it be possible to say that g(z) is differentiable at every z!=z0 (from the given info) and to check for differentiability at z=z0 by definition, and then conclude that it is anayltic at z0, instead of relying on Riemann's theorem?

Comment: I don't think so. If you could show that $g$ is differentiable at $z_0$ using only the definition of $g'(z_0)$, then that would work for real functions of a real variable too. But it doesn't: if $z_0=0$ and if$$f(z)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }z\in(0,\infty)\\-1&\text{ if }z\in(-\infty,0)\end{cases}$$then $\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$, but $g$ will be the absolute function, which is not diffeentiable at $0$.